# Visual Studio is blurry

Tags: visual-studio

I have a problem with Visual Studio. It's very blurry the whole IDE. Please help me. Thanks in advance [Preview of my Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CylJw.png)

Comment: What happens if you drag-and-drop the window to your second monitor?

Comment: @Heinzi I don't have a second monitor I am a developer as a hobbyist